# Android Studio 2.0, why won't the plugin successfully install?

Tags: android-studio, plugins, config

I tried install the plugin called **gitignore** so many times, and after click **apply** and **OK**, and restart the Android Studio, the plugin is **not in the list**, and in Android Studio, it notified me again to install the plugin.

How to fix it?

I have the idea.properties created in the user .AndroidStudio2.0 folder, and redirect (set) the *idea.system.path* and *idea.config.path* to other folders. That folder have all access from all users. Is it the cause of all these?

-------------Update---------------
It turns out that all the options are not saved. When I modified the settings, close and reopen Android Studio will reset all modified settings. I already have a solution, allow me to answer my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**idea.properties** was not correctly set.

*idea.system.path* and *idea.config.path* have the wrong path separate character. 
It should use "/" instead of "\".

Answer (score 0):

I could successfully install the plugin `.ignore` for gitignore. This works fine for me. This plugin was suggested from Android Studio. Maybe you can give it a try.